# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 error with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron

Запускается приложение, и спустя некоторое время, выдаётся ошибки что хром драйвер поддерживает только 74 версию, ну или любую другую, в зависимости от того какую версиюя драйвера я буду использовать. Ничего не понимаю, что он хочет...

```
        options.AddArguments("remote-debugging-port=4444", "no-sandbox");
        options.BinaryLocation = "****.exe"; //приложение 

        var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

Comment: у вас версия хрома какая?

Comment: версия chromedriver.exe должна быть ниже или равна версии браузера Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, нужно было просто чутка подумать. Приложение было сделано на базе электрона. Браузер был хром 68-ой версии. Взял 70-ую версию хром драйвера.